# Clear Form values at close

Tags: c#, asp.net, window, telerik-ajax

I´m trying to clear the values of an insert/edit form, which keep getting stored at a window after it closes, causing unexpected behaviour in my application, more specifically, not allowing it to open for a second time without full page reload.

So i found out that a proper way to do it would be by clearing the form at insert event, programatically. How should i do it properly? Or there is a better way?

```
// Creating form

(...) //some other code

EditTs.Objecto = ts; //Storing the edit/insert form values


//save method on button click
        {
            modeltable novo = new modeltable();

(...) //some other code

                listagembll.InsertFile(novo);

            }


        }


        RadScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "1", "Sys.Application.add_load(function(){{alert('O registo foi adicionado com sucesso!');}}, 500);", true);

 Objecto.Clear() ?????
    }
```

Comment: First of all, `EditTs.Objecto` and `Objecto` are not really the same thing. 
Using `Clear()` may or may not work. It depends on what type of object it is.

Comment: Object is a variable to store the attribute's values, conected to each attribute. EdiTs is the form identifier. So i bind the values to the form. Sorry if i didn´t´ make myself clear. My implementation is working, but only one time, at the second try, if there is no postback, the form isn´t open, and i´'m getting null values error